# How do i join 2 queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select a.nume_echipament,
       a.producator,
       a.seria,
       b.uc,
       b.port ,

          a.durata_aprovizionare as durata_aprovizionare,
      ( SELECT  sec_to_time(count(starea)*5) from echipamente inner join
aprovizionari on 
echipamente.nume_echipament=aprovizionari.nume_echipament 
where
(
echipamente.ora>aprovizionari.ora_aprov
and
echipamente.data>aprovizionari.data_aprov)
and starea='1'
and
 echipamente.nume_echipament='automat_imbuteliere') as durata_functionare,
       a.durata_viata as durata_viata,
      ( select data_aprov from aprovizionari where nume_echipament='automat_imbuteliere' order by date(data_aprov) desc, time(ora_aprov) desc limit 1) as data_aprov,
      ( select ora_aprov from aprovizionari where nume_echipament='automat_imbuteliere' order by date(data_aprov) desc, time(ora_aprov) desc limit 1) as ora_aprov,
      (select sec_to_time(count(starea)*5)) as durata_totala 

       from date_tehnice a
       inner join echipamente b on a.nume_echipament=b.nume_echipament
       inner join aprovizionari c on c.nume_echipament=a.nume_echipament
       where a.nume_echipament='automat_imbuteliere'
       and
       b.starea='1';
```

The above query work perfectly fine, but i also need to get the result from this query

```
select `starea` from echipamente where nume_echipament='automat_imbuteliere' order by data desc, ora desc limit 1 ;
```

As you can see in the first query it depends only on b.starea='1', whereas the second query needs to get the latest value of 'starea'. 'starea' has only 0 and 1 values.  So, how do i combine this 2 queries into 1 query in order to get the last value value of 'starea'?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you want your result to be formatted, but it sounds like you want the UNION keyword.  It will merge two result sets as long as the have the same number of columns. You can pad one query with null columns to make them match.

Comment: i tried using union but it doesnt work because both queries must return the sambe number of columns in order to work

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/ejtxit04p/ @MartianCodeHound, this is how it looks like the first query, and at the end i want to fetch the result of the second query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the second query to have its own row then UNION them like this with as many null columns as needed to match the number of columns in your first query.

```
UNION
select 
(select `starea` from echipamente where nume_echipament='automat_imbuteliere' order by data desc, ora desc limit 1 )
, null
, null
, null 
, null 
, null
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'data' in 'order clause'
I dont understand why i get this error...i have column data in 'echipamente'

Comment: Oh, its trying to order the results after the UNION.  I've modified the answer to correct that.

Comment: good, it works.....can i ask you how to fetch that last column in php?               like i have this: foreach( $result as $row ) {   .....}.. What do i write between the brackets to get that value from the query after union?